# Elements in the intersection of the groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $H = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ 
and $K = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$

Find the elements of the subgroup $$H \cap K$$

My approach:

Since $H\cap K$ is sugroup of H and K, it contains the trivial element, the identity element. Since 2 and 4 are not co-prime, there could exist other element in the intersection.

I'm not getting how to find the rest of the elements. Any help ?

Comment: Subgroup of what? $H$ is a set of cosets of $2{\mathbb Z}$ and $K$ is a set of cosets of $4{\mathbb Z}$, so $H \cap K$ is empty and cannot be subgroup of anything.

Answer (score 1):

The question makes no sense, since as you present them $H$ and $K$ are abstract groups and there is no intersection between such.

If you want to speak of an intersection, you need to embed them into one larger group, (to see them as *subgroups* of a larger group).

There you will be able to discuss the intersection. It is also possible to discuss what the intersection can possibly be, given the orders of the elements.